# Converting multiple matrices to images and saving them is taking forever to complete

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

`x_data` here is a list of size `10560` where each element is an array of size `2000x7`. I am trying to plot each matrix and save it as a `.jpg` file and I am using this code for that. It seems to be working but it is taking forever to finish. Is there any faster way to do it?

```
for idx, x in enumerate(x_data):
  plt.plot(x)
  plt.savefig('EMG_img/{}_gesture{}.jpg'.format(idx,(y_augmented[idx]).tolist().index(1.0)))
  print('EMG_img/{}_gesture{}.jpg'.format(idx,(y_augmented[idx]).tolist().index(1.0)),' ...')
```

`y_augmented` contains the corresponding label in `one-hot-encoding` format (for machine learning) and i am just using it here for file naming purposes

output:

```
EMG_img/0_gesture7.jpg  ...
EMG_img/1_gesture6.jpg  ...
EMG_img/2_gesture9.jpg  ...
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you plotting all those arrays in the same figure? Why?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest How can I avoid that? I am not experienced with plotting .. thank you

Comment: `plt.figure()` creates a figure. `plt.close()` closes the figure (to free the memory). Also, first only loop over some of the data to see if the resulting figures are what you expect.

Comment: that solved it.. thanks buddy!!